# What is difference between NodeJS http and https module?

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, http, ssl-certificate

I am using http module in my project but most of my 'post' requests are blocked by postman.
I read it is a ssl issue,after some research i found another module named  https.

Here is my current code.

```
 var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hei, make sure that the interceptor in Postman is off (it should be in the top, left to the "Sign in" button)

And related to https, as stated in Node.js v5.10.1 Documentation

> HTTPS is the HTTP protocol over TLS/SSL. In Node.js this is implemented as a separate module.

I used it once to make requests from my server to other servers over https (port 443).

btw, your code shouldn't work, try this

```
const http = require('http');
http.createServer( (request, response) => {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

and use http://127.0.0.1:8124 in Postman
..hoped it helped

Comment: Thank you! 
My code is functional and it was my mistake not to copy all the code. I thought it would be irrelevant here. 
Test service on '/' is working fine with localhost:3000

Actually most of the code is pre generated for with express-generator. 
I am using my own architecture on the top. 

Thank you and very appreciated for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `HTTP` and `HTTPS` is if you need to communicate with the servers over `SSL`, encrypting the communication using a certificate, you should use `HTTPS`, otherwise you should use `HTTP`, for example:

With `HTTPS` you can do something like that:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'ssl', 'prd', 'cert.key')).toString(),
    cert : fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'ssl', 'prd', 'cert.crt')).toString(),
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server = server.listen(443, function() {
    console.log("Listening " + server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const http = require('http');
http.createServer( function(request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-text exchanged using **HTTP** goes as plain text
i.e. anyone between the browser and server can read it relatively easily if one intercepts this exchange of data due to which it is Insecure.

**HTTPS** is considered to be secure but at the cost of processing time.
This is because Web Server and Web Browser need to exchange encryption keys using Certificates before actual data can be transferred.

**HTTP** works on Application layer.
**HTTPS** works on Transport layer.
This makes HTTPS more secure, encrypted but little bit slower than HTTP.